# How to return what is missing from a 2 column list comparing against all possible combinations of 2 single column lists?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

Sample data:

```
  A     B          C         D            E     F
1 name  handed in  students  assignments  name  missing
2 a     1          a         1            b     2
3 b     1          b         2            b     3
4 c     1          c         3            c     2
5 a     2
6 c     3
7 a     3
```

Say I am a teacher so:

- C has a list of all students enrolled in my class;
- D has a list of all assignments;
- Each and every student in C must hand in all of the assignments listed in D;
- A and B I keep feeding with student name and assignment handed in.

Now, at the end of the day, I wanna know who are the bad students who have not handed in all of their assignments.

I need a formula that lists in E and F the student name and the assignments they were supposed to have handed in.

In my sample data student "a" is a good student, student "b" missed out assignments 2 and 3 and student "c" missed out assignment 2.

Comment: let's say you are a teacher, are columns C and D somehow generated or they are just manually typed

Comment: Manually typed but must be dynamic, that is, I might insert or remove data at will.

Comment: I figure we must start out finding a way of dynamically creating a list from C and D containing, in our sample, 9 item pairs. So a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3. Then we can quite easily find out what pairs are not in A and B.

Comment: I see, so you actually need to calculate C, D, E, F based on A and B, right?

Comment: Yeah, from C and D you must create a list of all possible combinations. E and F gotta be the list of items from the "all possible combinations" which are not present in A and B.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHou_m7m5B5d0Fg_QRg2hgPU1ADxZ9RICEAnxL6aWjY/edit#gid=0) to see a demo.

Explanation:

- G and H shows all the possible combinations of C and D;
- "I" tell us which combination in G and H are not present in A and B;
- E2 queries G through I and returns the rows where "I" are TRUE.

---

**Edit**

[Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHou_m7m5B5d0Fg_QRg2hgPU1ADxZ9RICEAnxL6aWjY/edit#gid=869281356) for a single (E2), improved and compact formula.

Comment: @MARK I managed to trim down the formula. It's really short now. Take a look at http://bit.ly/2EmwU9u

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY({
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(C2:C&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(D2:D)),  CHAR(9))),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(D2:D&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(C2:C))), CHAR(9)))},
 "where Col1 is not null", 0), ARRAYFORMULA(IF(QUERY({
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(C2:C&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(D2:D)),  CHAR(9))),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(D2:D&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(C2:C))), CHAR(9)))},
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)="", ,ISNA(VLOOKUP({QUERY({
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(C2:C&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(D2:D)),  CHAR(9))),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(D2:D&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(C2:C))), CHAR(9)))},
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)}&{QUERY({
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(C2:C&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(D2:D)),  CHAR(9))),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(D2:D&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(C2:C))), CHAR(9)))},
 "select Col2 where Col2 is not null", 0)}, {A2:A}&{B2:B}, 1, 0))))}, 
 "select Col1, Col2 where Col3=TRUE order by Col1"))
```

[image]

- ### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHou_m7m5B5d0Fg_QRg2hgPU1ADxZ9RICEAnxL6aWjY/edit#gid=1329553011)

Answer (score 0):

- **mathematical solution:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({FILTER(D2:D, D2:D<>""),
 IF(LEN( QUERY(A2:B, "select sum(B) where B is not null group by A label sum(B)''", 0)),
 IF(E2:E-QUERY(A2:B, "select sum(B) where B is not null group by A label sum(B)''", 0)<0, ,
    E2:E-QUERY(A2:B, "select sum(B) where B is not null group by A label sum(B)''", 0)), )},
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

- **cell D2:** **`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""))`**

Comment: I get an error, take a look at http://bit.ly/2Gyhq4t

Anyhow, from your screenshot, the result in G and H are not correct. I mean, student "b" has handed in their assignment 1.

Comment: Another issue is if, for instance, I want to insert the student "d" who, at this point, has handed in none of the assignments.

Comment: B column needs to be formated as number not text. and for student d... well it acounts that you wont type in student name unless he handed over something xD

Comment: Yeap! that was it. Changed to number formatting and got the same result as yours.

Comment: its a different approach... in this scenario student "a" handed over 6 assignments but it required only 1 of him to hand over so he is 5 ahead...

Comment: Well, D is my enrollment list. I mean, this spreadsheet is meant to be only a thought experiment. In really I will have a separated spreadsheet for enrolled students, another for listing the assignments given to them, and so on.

Comment: student "a" must hand in only 3 assignments. I updated the question adding "Each and every student in C must hand in all of the assignments listed in D"

Comment: Actually, what I am doing has nothing to do with students neither school assignments. I just borrowed the logic to facilitate everyone's understanding of what is being asked.